# How to use Expandable sections in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, slds

I am using Expandable sections in my project. All works fine but when I click the expand (left) icon, it changes to (down) icon to expand the section. But when I refresh the page, it again becomes (left) icon with section expanded (Image)[image]

Code HTML

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-section slds-is-open" data-id={id}>
        <!--section header-->
        <h3 class="slds-section__title">
            <button type="button" aria-controls={id} class="slds-button slds-section__title-action" data-buttonid={id}
                onclick={toggleSection}>
                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:switch" alternative-text="button icon" size="x-small"
                    class="slds-section__title-action-icon slds-button__icon_left"></lightning-icon>
                <span class="slds-truncate" title={label}>{label}</span>
            </button>
        </h3>
        <!--section body-->
        <div class="slds-section__content">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Code - JS

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
export default class ExpandableSection extends LightningElement {
    @api id;
    @api label;

    toggleSection(event) {
        let buttonid = event.currentTarget.dataset.buttonid;
        let currentsection = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="' + buttonid + '"]');
        if (currentsection.className.search('slds-is-open') == -1) {
            currentsection.className = 'slds-section slds-is-open';
        } else {
            currentsection.className = 'slds-section slds-is-close';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "when you refresh the page"? I've tried to replicate your problem without success. Please be as specific as possible.